# Does SSL provide client authentication (RESTful)?

Tags: web-services, security, rest

If so, how so?

If not, what technologies/patterns to employed with it to provide such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring client certificate can provide client authentication.

Configuration depends on server you use. Distribution/creation of client certificates is another issue you need to solve for your particular case.

Note: I don't see relation to REST...

Comment: I see. Perhaps I should elaborate more on my context. I am developing a Windows service to collect data on the internet performance of the users machine. Users will be forced to have accounts to log this data on my server, however, I need to be sure that the user is not manually tampering with the data (internet latency), like simply editing the payload that he/she sees coming out with false data. 

Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: @Zerkz - your comment don't seem to have anything to do with your question... your probably want to ask new one (or edit this one to change to completely different question) - "how to prevent client from tampering with data on its own machine"...

Comment: I see. I believe I will just encrypt the payload and just try to obfuscate the key that it was encrypted with.